# how to stop uiwebview scrolling in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a webview in my view. and i want to stop scrolling of that webview.
i am not getting how to stop the scrolling of the webview.

please give some good idea.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set  UserinteractionEnabled:No.

So that it cannot be scrolled

Comment: this will disable all the interactions within web view... so any interaction within html pages will not work. This is helpful only to display static html content.